# Python Scrapy scrapes wrong information

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data, but the output is weird. The information I am scraping is the name of the country and the population from this page [LINK](http://geoba.se/country.php?cc=DE). But the output is:

```
['United States'] 328,131,075
```

This makes no sense to me, because I am scraping from the page, that contains the Information about Germany.

This is my code:

```
allowed_domains = ["geoba.se/country.php?cc=DE"]
start_urls = ['http://geoba.se/country.php?cc=DE/']

def parse(self, response):

    country = response.xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/b/text()').extract()
    pop_total = response.xpath('//td/div/table/tr/td[2]/text()').extract_first()

    print(country, pop_total)
```

What am I missing here? The Result should be:

```
['Germany'] 80,594,017
```

When I use scrapy shell I get the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your start_urls. It should be "http://geoba.se/country.php?cc=DE" (without the final slash bar), otherwise the site brings you always on the USA page.